# Count row when left join returns multiple for row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting rows with left join. t2 can return mulitple rows based on the where clause.
This query returns the count from the t2 table, how do I count the result from t1. I've tried added group by t1.id, but this only returns 1.

Thanks!

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS number_of_rows
FROM t1
LEFT JOINt2 ON t1.id=t2.t1_id
WHERE t2.row='?' OR t2.row='?'
```

Comment: since there is one to many relation (t1->t2), `COUNT(t1.id)` will always going to return 1

Comment: So how can I fix this? I tried swithing t2 and t1 and still the same result.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.id) AS number_of_rows
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.row='?' OR t2.row='??' GROUP BY t1_id
) t2 ON t1.id=t2.t1_id
```

This seems to work for me. I was surprised I had to count t2.id and not t1.id. Can anyone explain me this?

Comment: If (as appears to be the case) you want to understand what's going on without aggregation, execute the same query without aggregation.